# AskForFolderName and check if folder Exists in .bat

Tags: batch-file

I have this piece of code which I made some time ago. It is a simple check to prompt the user to put in a different name if the folder name exists. For some reason it does not work. If the folder exists it **should** `Goto AskForFolderName`. I cannot figure it out.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
mode 90,10
color a

::Stage 3 - Check Folder
    :AskForFolderName

    set /p NewFolder=What is the name of the iteam being sold? 
    If ["%NewFolder%"]==[] Goto AskForFolderName
    If Exist "%NewFolder%" (
       Echo Folder already exists
       Echo.
       Goto AskForFolderName
    )


    Mkdir "003 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%"
    Move "002 - Process Images\"*.* "003 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%"
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 20 > nul
    exit
```

Comment: Both sides of a comparison should be enclosed only by double quotes to avoid errors when empty. So replace `If ["%NewFolder%"]==[]` with `If "%NewFolder%"==""`

Comment: @LotPings, I gave that a go.. No anvil.

Comment: @LotPings I have added all the code to have a better clarity.

Comment: If the code snippet is enclosed in a (code block) you'll need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: @LotPings I have added it.. You can see in my code. But still no go.

Comment: The `if exist` checks the current folder and you expect it to magically check in `"003 - Images Ready\"`? Also your quoting doesn't match in `Move "002...`

Comment: @LotPings It does come up with the message correctly saying: `A subdirectory or file 003 - Images Ready\123 already exists`. However, it then continues forwards to move the images to the 123 folder. So it knows that a folder with the same name exists.

Comment: I think it scans all the folders in the directory of the BAT

Comment: That's nonsense, there is no command to scan anything.

Comment: @LotPings Well thank you.. Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
mode 90,10
color a

::Stage 3 - Check Folder
:AskForFolderName

set /p "NewFolder=What is the name of the iteam being sold? "
If "%NewFolder%"=="" Goto :AskForFolderName
If Exist "003 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\" (
   Echo Folder already exists
   Echo.
   Goto AskForFolderName
)

Mkdir "003 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%" 
Move  "002 - Process Images\*.*" "003 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%"
Timeout /NoBreak /T 20 > nul
exit
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a trailing back slash, `If Exist "003 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\"`; _otherwise the `If Exist` may find a file there with the name `%NewFolder%` and report that a directory with that name exists_.